# Display monitor timings calculate

Tags: linux

i have such structure, where wrote monitor timings:

```
   [MVDU_MODE_HD_720_P_50] = {
        .width = 1280,
        .height = 720,
        .vmode = MVDU_MODE_PROGRESSIVE,
        .pixclock = 74250000,
        .mode = 0x17,
        .h_blank = 692,
        .h_active = 1280,
        .h_total = 1980,
        .hs_start = 440,
        .hs_len = 40,
        .hs_delay = 220,
        .v_blank_beg = 25,
        .v_active = 720,
        .v_total = 750,
        .v_blank_end = 5,
        .vs_start = 0,
        .vs_len = 5,
        .vs_p = 1,
}
```

So, and i have fixed

1. v_total = 780-806;
2. v-active = 768;
3. h_total=1,344;
4. h-active= 1024;
5. pixclock= 74250000 or 27000000.

**How i can calculate other parameters ???**

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: What other parameters?

Comment: @Dominique i am talking about monitor timings. Trying create my own timings.

Comment: @jww h_blank, hs_start, hs_len, hs_delay, v_blank_beg and .v_blank_end.

Comment: I have got answer. If you wanna calculate your own timing parameters, you can use VESA timing calculators or read  only take parameters from VESA standard or any another standard.